# Selenium DriverFactory Safari

Tags: javascript, selenium

I'm trying to get TestNG to create a script that will Launch my Script in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. My code below works for Chrome and Firefox, but it won't launch Safari. I can run regular Selenium Scripts in Safari, but I can't make a DriverFactory Work. Any tips, Sorry this is my 1st Question. Thanks for any help

```js
package advance.Base;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;

public class BrowserDriverFactory {

 private ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();
 private String browser;
 
 public BrowserDriverFactory(String browser) {
  this.browser = browser.toLowerCase();
 }
 
 public WebDriver createDriver() {
  // Create driver
  System.out.println("create driver: " + browser);
  
  switch (browser) {
  case "chrome":
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "//Users///Desktop//Selenium Folder//ChromeDriver//chromedriver");
   driver.set(new ChromeDriver());
   break;
   
  case "firefox":
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "//Users//Desktop//Selenium Folder//GeckoDriver//geckodriver");
   driver.set(new FirefoxDriver());
   break;
   
  case "safari":
   driver.set(new SafariDriver());
   break;
  }
  
  return driver.get();
  
 }
```

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by "you can't make driver factory work"?. What is the test code you tried? I used your code and it is working for me!!

Comment: I messed up, I needed to have a Safari Test Parameter in my xml file. Thanks